# How to keep same image during update in laravel without choosing image once again?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to update some records. Though I didnot want update image and click on update buuton, It shows me error-

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Here is my **controller**

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
      $participants = new participants;

         $file = $request->file("select_file");

          if($request->hasfile("select_file"))
          {
            $file->move("public/images/",$file->getClientOriginalName());
          }

            $id                   = $request->id;
            $First_name          =  $request->First_name;
            $Last_name           =  $request->Last_name;
            $Date_of_Birth       =  $request->Date_of_Birth;
            $GST_no             =  $request->GST_no;
            $email              =  $request->email;
            $Mobile_No           =  $request->Mobile_No;
            $Company_name        =  $request->Company_name;
            $Address             =  $request->Address;
            $State              =  $request->State;
            $City               =  $request->City;
            $Pincode             =  $request->Pincode;
            $Country             =  $request->Country;
            $Amount              =  $request->Amount;
            // $Image                = $request->Image;
            $Image                = $file->getClientOriginalName();


    DB::table('participants')
     ->where('id',$id )
    ->update(['First_name'=>$First_name,'Last_name'=>$Last_name,'Date_of_Birth'=>$Date_of_Birth,'GST_no'=>$GST_no,'email'=>$email,'Mobile_No'=>$Mobile_No,'Company_name'=>$Company_name,'Address'=>$Address,'State'=>$State,'City'=>$City,'Pincode'=>$Pincode,'Country'=>$Country,'Amount'=>$Amount,'Image'=>$Image]);


    $participants->update();



    session()->flash('success','Data Updated successfully!');
    return redirect()->back();
    //return back()->with('error','Update Data successfully!');
    }
```

**view** page

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="File" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Image') }}</label>
       <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="file" name="select_file" class="form-control" value="{{$input[0]->Image}}">
       <img src="/public/images/{{$input[0]->Image}}" alt="Image not Found" style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want the data to be updated with previous image(since I donot want to update image).

Answer (score 1):

Make the change like this:

```
$file = $request->file("select_file");

if($request->hasfile("select_file"))
{
    $file->move("public/images/",$file->getClientOriginalName());
    $Image                = $file->getClientOriginalName();
}

$id                   = $request->id;
$First_name          =  $request->First_name;
$Last_name           =  $request->Last_name;
$Date_of_Birth       =  $request->Date_of_Birth;
$GST_no             =  $request->GST_no;
$email              =  $request->email;
$Mobile_No           =  $request->Mobile_No;
$Company_name        =  $request->Company_name;
$Address             =  $request->Address;
$State              =  $request->State;
$City               =  $request->City;
$Pincode             =  $request->Pincode;
$Country             =  $request->Country;
$Amount              =  $request->Amount;
// $Image                = $request->Image;
```

Now `$file->getClientOriginalName();` will only be called when there is file uploaded.

Comment: Error generated : ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: Image

Comment: @Shallokikundu did you uncommented the last $image variable?, there will be only one $image variable in if condition.

Comment: No, that was the mistake I was doing. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 1):

More like you should change the image only when a new one is uploaded otherwise leave it the same

$file = $request->file("select_file");

```
if($request->hasfile("select_file")) {
    $file->move("public/images/",$file->getClientOriginalName());
    $Image                = $file->getClientOriginalName();
} else {
    $Image                = $request->Image;
}
```

because you are using `$Image` variable in your update statement later on which will give an undefined error if you only define $Image in your `if` statement.

Or you could take a better approach to enhance your overall script like so:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $update = [   
        'First_name' => $request->First_name,
        'Last_name' => $request->Last_name,
        'Date_of_Birth' => $request->Date_of_Birth,
        'GST_no' => $request->GST_no,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'Mobile_No' => $request->Mobile_No,
        'Company_name' => $request->Company_name,
        'Address' => $request->Address,
        'State' => $request->State,
        'City' => $request->City,
        'Pincode' => $request->Pincode,
        'Country' => $request->Country,
        'Amount' => $request->Amount
    ];

    $file   = $request->file("select_file");
    if ($request->hasfile("select_file")) {
        $file->move("public/images/", $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $update['Image'] = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    DB::table('participants')->where('id', $id)->update($update);

    session()->flash('success', 'Data Updated successfully!');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnot worked. When I am updating, the image field is becomes null everytime. :(

Comment: You need to send over the path of the image or whatever it is you save in the database for image reference as "Image" on the update so that you can maintain it. If you send null as Image on update, of course it will update as null and you will loose the image everytime you update, makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

  $participants = new participants;

        $id     = $request->id;
        $file   = $request->file("select_file");

    if($request->hasfile("select_file"))
    {
        $file->move("public/images/",$file->getClientOriginalName());
        $Image                = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        DB::table('participants')
                ->where('id',$id )
                ->update(['Image'=>$Image]);
    }

        $id                   = $request->id;
        $First_name          =  $request->First_name;
        $Last_name           =  $request->Last_name;
        $Date_of_Birth       =  $request->Date_of_Birth;
        $GST_no             =  $request->GST_no;
        $email              =  $request->email;
        $Mobile_No           =  $request->Mobile_No;
        $Company_name        =  $request->Company_name;
        $Address             =  $request->Address;
        $State              =  $request->State;
        $City               =  $request->City;
        $Pincode             =  $request->Pincode;
        $Country             =  $request->Country;
        $Amount              =  $request->Amount;


DB::table('participants')
 ->where('id',$id )
->update(['First_name'=>$First_name,'Last_name'=>$Last_name,'Date_of_Birth'=>$Date_of_Birth,'GST_no'=>$GST_no,'email'=>$email,'Mobile_No'=>$Mobile_No,'Company_name'=>$Company_name,'Address'=>$Address,'State'=>$State,'City'=>$City,'Pincode'=>$Pincode,'Country'=>$Country,'Amount'=>$Amount]);


$participants->update();



session()->flash('success','Data Updated successfully!');
return redirect()->back();
//return back()->with('error','Update Data successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a working one but can be made better for three following reasons: 1. your code can be organized and made way more compact. 2. You are initializing "participants" model which you anyway do not use as you use query builder for update so that is there for no reason. 3. You are using two queries to update the data whereas you can do it by using just one. I have updated my answer to provide you the final full code, have a look.